# React native Skia is not compatible with babylon

Tags: react-native, babylonjs, skia

I am trying to use [react-native-skia](https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia/) with @babylonjs/react-native(1.6.1) and RN 0.71 but can not use both of them together. Only of them is visible on the screen.

I had the same problem earlier with RN 0.70 where skia drawings were not available in debug mode(or when app was connected to metro) but only with reract-native-skia version 0.1.157, I have managed to have both libraries available at the same time.

I can't think of a reason why this is happening, any thoughts? is it the canvas that is blocked?